# Using Drivine and Neo4j, how can inline a query as a string, rather than injecting a separate file

Tags: node.js, typescript, neo4j, graph-databases, drivine

I'm using [Drivine](https://drivine.org), with Neo4j. The example shows how to inject a query stored in a separate file. How can I simply inline a query as a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea behind having a separate file is so that queries can be profiled, tested and have a life-cyle in their own right. You don't have to use this if it doesn't suit you.

The [example](https://github.com/liberation-data/drivine-inspiration/blob/master/src/health/HealthRepository.ts) also shows how to create inline queries:

```
async countAllVertices(): Promise<number> {
    const results = await this.persistenceManager.query<any>(
        new QuerySpecification(`match (n) return count(n) as count`)
    );

    return results[0].count;
}
```

For simple queries that don't need to be profiled or heavily tested, inline is easier.